# "Been so long *since*" + Present Perfect Tense

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary, present-perfect

I'd like to ask:

*What's the meaning of present perfect using it after  _been so long since_*?

For example:

> *Someone phones me and says:*
>
> It's been so long *since I've talked to you*.

Or for example:

> It's been so longe *since I've had this much fun*.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Actually, these are examples of the present perfect reflecting perfect aspect. That is a bit unusual in modern English, but it is perfectly grammatical. More common would be "since I talked to you" and "since I had this much fun." The implication from the perfect aspect is that we completed talking at a past instant but not until now has it been repeated  and that I did have as much fun at a past instant but not until now has it been repeated.

Comment: Oh, my apologies , Colin, I will edit the question.

Comment: Jeff:Just to see if  I got it right - We used the present Perfect here to show that  something's been repeated. For example: "It's been so long since I've talked to you" - I haven't talked to you for years. And now I'm doing so, because I'm talking to you right now.